# 404 not found in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I need a test function but it is not working. Supposedly with Routing + Controller should work, but I get a 404 not found.

This is my `/app/config/routing.yml`:

```
AndroidAPIBundle:
    resource: "@MDPIAndroidApiBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Inside `Controller` directory I have `LoginController.php`:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/test", name="test")
 */
public function getAction(Request $request)
{
    $format = "json";
    $view = View::create()->setStatusCode(201)->setData(array("status"=>"OK", "data"=>array("test" => "DAN TEST")))->setFormat($format);
    return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
}
```

So why when I make a curl request I get a 404 message? Also in browser adding `/api/test` to my local url.

**EDIT**

```
php app/console router:debug

test                                         ANY    ANY    ANY  /api/test
```

**EDIT 2**

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/susy_android_final`

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             susy.android.final.local;
    access_log              /var/log/nginx/susy_android_final.access.log;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/susy_android_final.error.log;
    root                    /var/www/susy.mdpi.com.final/web;

    client_max_body_size 500M;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 64k; 

    location / {
            index app_dev.php;
            if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
            }
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php last;
    }
    ## Parse all .php file in the /var/www directory
   location ~ (app|app_dev|app_eudev).php {
            fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;                
            fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock; 
            #fastcgi_pass                   127.0.0.1:9001; 
            #fastcgi_index                  index.php;
            fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
            include                         fastcgi_params;

   }


}
```

`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 susy.android.final.local
```

This is in ubuntu

Comment: What do you have when you visit **yourdomain/api/test** ? And can you please check if the route is shown in your console when you type this command :

`php bin/console debug:router`

It maybe `php app/console debug:router` if you are using old version of Symfony

Comment: When i visit my domain i get 
   `404 Not Found
    nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`
And this for the command `[InvalidArgumentException]              
  Command "debug:router" is not defined. `

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using ?

Comment: Symfony version 2.3.42 - app/dev/debug

Comment: cd to your project root directory and type in this command `php app/console debug:router` and show us the result you will get.

Comment: `[InvalidArgumentException]              
  Command "debug:router" is not defined. `

Thanks for the help teeyo

Comment: it's weird, I worked with Symfony 2.4 back in 2011 and I'm sure I used the console to debug routes when I needed to with this command. And here it is in the documentation page for **Symfony 2.3** : https://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/routing.html#visualizing-debugging-routes

Comment: aaah it was $ php app/console router:debug

Comment: Yes it's what I wrote in the first comment bro !! So what do you get from typing it ?

Comment: `router:debug` worked but `debug:router` not. My class was extending another Controller and it was not imported with use :)

Comment: Yes `debug:router` is for recent Symfony versions, well glad it helps I just read my first command, I tried to give you the two commands for old and new version but gave you only the recent one twice lol sorry for that.

Comment: `test                                         ANY    ANY    ANY  /api/test`

Comment: @teeyo although the route looks good, my curl request still gives me 404, also by browser :(

Comment: @DanWearsPrada What's the cURL command you're running ?

Comment: @DanWearsPrada whatever it is, could you run it as `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" /api/test`

Comment: Yes I can, but i get the same error

Comment: Can you post your NGINX config ? Are you sure you configured it properly ? Meaning rewritting app.php out ?

Comment: In `etc/nginx` i have the sites-enabled/sites-available thing. Where is app.php?

Comment: What if you remove the keyword `api` from route and replace it with other `application/test` it may be possible some other bundle is using this keyword

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid just did that and still 404 :(

Comment: For me it look's like problem with rewrite in nginx configuration, can u paste error log and access logg. Symfony log will be nice to ;)

Comment: @DanWearsPrada the question is are you getting 404 from nginx or from symfony? There could be issues with permissions. Do you see any error at susy_android_final.error.log? or at app/logs/dev/log?

Answer (score 4):

## Make sure your domain is visible to Windows

The first step you should take to debug this issue is make sure Windows understands what `www.yourdomain.com` is and where it is located. To do this, you need to modify Windows's `hosts` file, which should be located in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\` folder. I personally like to create a shortcut for that file on my Desktop so it is easier to find whenever I need it. Open the file in Notepad++ (or whatever text editor you like), go to the end of the file, and add the following lines:

```
# replace with your VM's IP address
255.255.255.0 www.yourdomain.com
```

You can keep adding domains if you want to, just make sure you have a corresponding domain defined on your VM. Also make sure your VM has a static IP address, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264768/how-to-configure-static-ip-in-ubuntu-running-on-virtual-box) guide is fairly complete.

*Note, this step is only necessary if you are using a custom domain. If you use `http://localhost:8080/`, it shouldn't be a problem*

## Register the site in the Nginx config

If you created your project using Symfony's built in command, this step *shouldn't* be required. However, it doesn't hurt to check. Make sure the domain name correspond to the one in the `hosts` file described earlier, and that the root is defined correctly like so:

```
server {
    server_name yourdomain.tld www.yourdomain.tld;
    root /var/www/yourproject/web; # this is where app.php is located
```

You can find more on the minimum Nginx settings [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx).

## Check your firewalls settings

So you've done all the steps above and it still doesn't work, now what? Maybe Windows is simply blocking the requests to the VM, in which case, you need to go in your Windows firewall and allow [Virtual Host-Only](https://superuser.com/questions/936581/how-to-config-windows-firewall-so-vm-host-only-can-ping-windows-7) settings.

I don't think this is where your problem comes from, as you clearly get an error message from nginx, meaning the request does indeed reach your server. However I think it may be interesting to know for other people.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my hosts ile is ok, it redirects to localhost and the site is registered in sites available. I will update the question

Comment: @DanWearsPrada I just checked your edit, your host file should contain your VM's IP address, not `127.0.0.1`, which is your Window's "home" address

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to run the following command?

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Comment: for prod i get `[InvalidArgumentException]                                                          
  The file "/var/www/susy.mdpi.com.final/app/config/config_prod.yml" does not exist. `

and for dev `[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                               
  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "web_profiler" (in /var/www/susy.mdpi.com.final/app/config/config_dev.yml). Looked for namespace "web_profiler"...`

Comment: Does the file exist and what are the permissions on the file: `/var/www/susy.mdpi.com.final/app/config/config_prod.yml`

Comment: sorry i have no bin/console, just app/console. Not sure if this helps

Comment: It’s the same it was moved from app to bin in later Symfony versions

Answer (score 2):

looks like you have `.htaccess` in your `web` directory with rewrite/redirect rules, since you moved the .htaccess rules to your virtual host configuration file delete the content of .htaccess file and try again

Comment: emptied .htaccess nad still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you have configured your symfony correctly but something between your browser and symfony is broken. 
I would recommend to write a functional test for your config

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/testing.html

```
namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class LoginControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testGetAction()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('GET', '/api/test');
        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
    }
}
```

If your the test work, everthing is okay with your config. Then you should take a look if you land on the right webserver and configure the webserver for symfony ( usually the root should be in the web folder )